# Received "Request was cancelled" error when writing JSON data to HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, .net, monodevelop, xamarin

I've a iOS application written in C# using Monodevelop, and as part of the application I make a call to a web service. The web service call requires that JSON data to be written to the request. However, I receive an error the first time I attempt to write the data; all subsequent calls to the same method with the same parameters work. The following is a snippet of the relavent code:

```csh
// Start snippet

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create (_connectionSettings.Uri);
request.Timeout = 15000; // milliseconds
if (_connectionSettings.Username != "") {
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential (_connectionSettings.Username, _connectionSettings.Password);
}

if (post) {
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "application/json";
    if (jsonData != null) {
        byte[] byteArray = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonData);
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;    
        using (Stream ds = request.GetRequestStream()) {  //<--- ERROR HERE
            ds.Write (byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        }
    } else {
        request.Method = "GET";
}

using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse()) {

// end snippet
```

The error I get is as follows:

> System.Net.WebException: Request was cancelled. ---> 
>   System.Exception:
>   Cannot close the stream until all bytes are written
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---   at
>
> System.Net.WebConnectionStream.Close ()
>   [0x00121] in
>
> /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebConnectionStream.cs:785
>   at System.IO.Stream.Dispose () [0x00000] in
>
> /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/Stream.cs:93
>   at
>
> MyCustomMethod (System.String& responseString, System.String jsonData, Boolean post,
>   Boolean suppressAlert) [0x00101] in /Path/To/My/Class.cs:192

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

**EDIT**

**Ok, apparently when stepping through the application, the method works every time. What I've noticed is that when the error is throw, the request.ContentLength is zero despite the fact that the byteArray.Length is non-zero. However when stepping through the application, the request.ContentLength keeps the expected value of the byteArray.Length.**

Comment: can you try changing the statement using (Stream ds = request.GetRequestStream()) {  //<--- ERROR HERE
            ds.Write (byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        } to using (var ds = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream())) {  
            ds.Write (byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        } and see whether you still get the error.

Comment: @srsyogesh, thanks for the reply. There is no overload for StreamWriter.Write that accepts those parameters. However, using ds.Write(byteArray) throws the error "System.Net.ProtocolViolationException - The number of bytes to be written is greater than the specified ContentLength." It appears that the same issue is occurring that I noted in the edit, specifically request.ContentLength has a zero value even though byteArray.Length is non-zero.

Comment: can setting request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length will fix this ? not sure just a thought looking at the exception or as you mentioned in your edit these two values are already same ??

Comment: @srsyogesh Yes, before the using (Stream ds = request.GetRequestStream()) I set the request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length. Placing a breakpoint at that location, I see that the value for request.ContentLength is indeed equal to byteArray.Length. However, when I resume the application and the subsequent error is thrown, the value of request.ContentLength is then zero. Interestingly, if I don't resume the application but instead step through the application, the request.ContentLength remains equal to byteArray.Length, and the application works! Go figure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, it looks like we don't need to set the request.ContentLength at all. Removing the line:

```
request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
```

fixes the issue entirely. I'm still curious if this is a bug in the library as most of the code samples show setting the HttpWebRequest's ContentLength, and it works properly on subsequent tries.

Comment: msdn says this is required where data is being sent (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.contentlength.aspx), but you're right, on Xamarin removing the line fixes the problem.